# Non-manifold edges on shape with instances on vertices

Tags: 3d-printing, instances

I am using instances on vertices (AKA [DupliVerts](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=-_nSEEcEnEA)) on square shape to safe some memory.

When checking in [3D Print Toolbox](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/3d_print_toolbox.html) I get 4 non-manifold edges. Which are the edges of the square and not of the object on the vertices.

How can I hide just the square but not the instances? So far, if I hide the square, everything gets hidden.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the options? If you just want to _hide_ the square, you can do this by unchecking _Show Instancer_ > _Viewport_ and/or _Render_. But the square is still there and has non-manifold edges, it's just not visible. But that doesn't matter anyway - if you want to 3D print this, you cannot keep the instances as instances because they are no real geometry. You have to make the instances real, and as soon as you do that they are no longer dependent on the square and you can delete it to get rid of it.